# Splitting field of a set of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

Given $X\subseteq F[x]$ where $F$ is a field, how to prove that there exist a splitting field of $X$ over $F$?

In the case that $X$ is finite, I think the answer can be solved using *Kronecker's Theorem*, which states that every for every polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ there exist an extension field $E$ of $F$ containing a root of $f(x)$. Letting $f(x)$ be the product of all polynomial in $X$, one can proof by induction over $\deg f(x)$ that there is an extension field $K$ of $F$ containing a root of $f(x)$ and, therefore, an extension field $E$ of $F$ such that $f(x)$ splits in linear factors over $E[x]$; from this the result.

But what if $X$ is not finite? In general, how to proceed?

Comment: The field generated by  the roots of the elements of $X$  in an algebraic closure of $F$.

Comment: if $X$ is infinite, in particular when $X = F[x]$, you'll clearly need to define the whole algebraic closure. I don't see why there would be much more to say except maybe that "Using Zorn's lemma, it can be shown that every field has an algebraic closure" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure

Comment: Can't you give a proof that has any subset $X \subset F[x]$ has a splitting field and then consider the specific case $X = F[x]$ to obtain the algebraic closure?

Comment: Could we Zorn's lemma this without assuming the existence of an Algebraic Closure?

Comment: I concur with several of the comments above, especially @Jake’s. If you feel free to use the existence of an algebraic closure of $F$, then Bernard’s solution does the trick. If you do not feel so free, it’s a different problem entirely, and as far as I can see, you do need to Zornify in one way or another: either prove the existence of an algebraic closure, or prove that there’s a splitting field of your given $X$.